# Replace Opencv Fillpoly functions with Halide Funcs

Tags: opencv, halide

I'm trying to realize some opencv functions by Halide, one of the difficulty I have met is how to write the cv::fillpoly in Halide. This function, in opencv,  fills a polygon according to the given vertex of this polygon. The details in Opencv: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html

I wonder if it's possible to realize it in Halide?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but likely difficult and not obviously productive as polygon rendering does not have a regular static data parallel pattern and is already really well optimized in various places. It would be interesting to see if it can be done and made performant but it is a lot of work and isn't obviously going to be as fast or faster than existing graphics libraries. Especially if running on GPU hardware where it has to compete with hardware rasterization. I'd look into using `define_extern` to call out to existing rendering routines.